# computer produces light photos

Tags: contrast

I noticed recently when I copy an image from my pc to a thumb drive and connect it to a digital projector or a TV or a laptop comp. the image comes out lighter than that on my pc. I also tried a jpg image from my pc that had come out of the camera with no editing and had the same result. What could be causing this?

Comment: Lower brightness on computer monitor?

Comment: What is "lighter"? Less contrast or higher brightness?

Answer (score 1):

Neither of your devices appear calibrated. This would be an incredibly intriguing problem if all of your devices were calibrated to a standard...but since they're most likely not - differences in display should be expected.

For example, my home screen is perfectly calibrated. My work screen is old, has banding issues, and leans far too warm. And my iPhone is incredibly bright and contrasty - much punchier than what the image actually is.

Unless you've calibrated all of your devices, you should not expect them to display all the same. What you *can* do, however, is use one device to influence your settings changes on the others so that you get a somewhat consistent display. Please note that this is a bad idea if you want to take things to print, or do any color work, but you can adjust brightness and contrast to simply optimize for viewing. Just remember that if none of your devices is calibrated, adjusting them all to be the same means that they are *still* not calibrated, just "looking better" to you.

Comment: There's a profiling & photo display app for iOS if you have a X-Rite i1 colorimeter, btw. Doesn't fix it system-wide but really improves photos viewed via the app.

Answer (score 1):

Both TV screens and computer monitors have adjustment knobs. These adjustments might also be handled by software “ knobless”. We aware that modern display devices are adjustable as to darkness or lightness and contrast plus you can touchup the hue.

Now think about this: The modern camera takes a picture and displays it on its view-screen. This screen must work under dim and bright light conditions. I will bet that all the screens you are using are factory set and that you have never made any adjustments.

Now would be a good time to pull up the instruction manuals associated with your image viewing and make some touchups. You’ll feel better about your photography once learn about some of this stuff.